# Get All employees from the query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which gives me the data for the `Comp_mkey = 7 and 110`. The query is as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.comp_mkey,
            c.company_name,
            m.start_date,
            m.End_date,
            m.Process_date,
            m.Months_days,
            m.Process_year,
            m.Process_Month FROM emp_mst e,
            company_mst c,
            P_Monthly_Must_Para_Hdr m WHERE c.mkey = e.comp_mkey
            AND m.comp_mkey = e.comp_mkey
            AND (m.process_date IS NOT NULL
            AND (convert(varchar,(getDate()),103)) = convert(varchar,m.process_date + 1, 103))
            AND m.Process_year = 2016
            AND Process_month = 2
```

The query's output is as below:-

[image: Table output]

Now what I want is,

> All the employee names whose `comp_mkey` is in **7, 110**

Kindly let me know how to get that

I am using `SQL-server 2008`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just the name

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.Emp_name
FROM emp_mst e
WHERE e.comp_mkey IN ('7', '110')
```

Like you said use `IN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.comp_mkey, c.company_name, m.start_date, m.End_date, m.Process_date, m.Months_days, m.Process_year, m.Process_Month 
FROM emp_mst e, company_mst c, P_Monthly_Must_Para_Hdr m 
WHERE c.mkey = e.comp_mkey
AND m.comp_mkey = e.comp_mkey
AND (m.process_date IS NOT NULL
AND (convert(varchar,(getDate()),103)) = convert(varchar,m.process_date + 1, 103))
AND m.Process_year = 2016
AND Process_month = 2
AND m.comp_mkey IN ('7', '110')
```

Also you should use explicit joins like so.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.comp_mkey, c.company_name, m.start_date, m.End_date, m.Process_date, m.Months_days, m.Process_year, m.Process_Month 
FROM emp_mst e
INNER JOIN company_mst c ON c.mkey = e.comp_mkey
INNER JOIN P_Monthly_Must_Para_Hdr m ON m.comp_mkey = e.comp_mkey
WHERE (m.process_date IS NOT NULL
AND (convert(varchar,(getDate()),103)) = convert(varchar,m.process_date + 1, 103))
AND m.Process_year = 2016
AND Process_month = 2
AND m.comp_mkey IN ('7', '110')
```

Comment: what's the difference between both the query ? and after executing both the query, I did not get the `Employee Name` and the result is same

Comment: Whats your employee name field called?

Comment: Its called `Emp_name` in `emp_mst` table.

Comment: aah, thanks for that query too. If u don't mind can I ask u one more thing related to this only ?